# How to get the style attribute of a TextView

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I am creating a Custom TextView class MTextView . Inside the constructor i want to know the   value of style attrib of the textview so that I can set different typefaces depending on whether style is set to bold or not. But there is no getStyle() function ? What to do?

```
    public class MTextView extends TextView{

    public MTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            if(style.equals(TypeFace.bold))  //how to get style?
                setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"rc.ttf"));
    }



    }
```

Comment: what is `style` in this `if(style.equals(TypeFace.bold))` condition? where is declaration?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the textStyle from the TextView's `getTypeface()` instance method.

```
int style = getTypeface().getStyle();
```

If no textStyle has been specified (i.e. you want to support normal textStyle) then `getTypeface()` can return null.

In the case where it is not null it may be best to assume textStyle is implicitly set to normal.

Comment: The guy clearly wants to get style but not from default typeface, as he creates it from ttf file. Should not be marked as answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    if (attrs != null) {
        try {
            int style = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(
                "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
                "textStyle", 
                Typeface.NORMAL);

            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
                            getContext().getAssets(), 
                            "rc.ttf"), 
                        style);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```